# How can I install ntpstat on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ntp

I'm running Ubuntu server 10.04 64-bit.

What I've tried:

- apt-get. doesn't know of it.
- downloading rpm from [here](http://people.redhat.com/rkeech/#ntpstat) and converting with alien

  dpkg-gencontrol: error: current host architecture 'amd64' does not appear in package's architecture list (i386)

Comment: Why do you need ntpstat? Isn't `ntpq -p` appropriate?

Comment: I just need the 0/1 exit code that ntpstat provides for our app monitoring system. I already have this working on CentOS and I'm trying to reuse it.

Answer (score 3):

not a very good way, but it will do:

```
download the source rpm
rpm2cpio ntpstat-0.2-1.src.rpm | cpio -idmv
unpack the tgz
make && make install
```

but this is such a small utility, maybe save yourselve the hassle and use another tool that comes with ubuntu.

Comment: That works, thanks. Modern package managers have spoiled me.

Answer (score 1):

Following jojoo's answer, you should be able to run something like "ntpdc -c sysinfo" or "ntpdc -c peers" to get similar information.  It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to return a simple true/false value to our app monitoring software. That seems to be ntpstat's raison d'etre. Everything else I've tried is too heavyweight. Thanks